# Using ilrepack in a .netstandard project to merge all assemblies from a nuget package

Tags: .net, nuget, project.json, ilrepack

I'm building a public nuget package from a .NetStandard project. This project uses a private nuget package (from a private nuget server) targeting .netStandard too.

Before switching to .net standard, nuget references were in package.config, and building the project results in all referenced assemblies being copied in the bin/release folder. From there it was easy to use ilrepack in a post build task.

Now that the project uses project.json to reference nuget packages, after building the project, the bin/Release folder contains only the main assembly, not the assemblies from the referenced nuget package.

How would you use ilrepack from there ?

I should be able to reference the repacked assembly in another project in the same solution by adding a reference to this project. Can it still be done ? (it was working when package.config was used)